# mysql: update millions of records by applying a python function

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python function (**pyfunc**):

```
def pyfunc(x):
    ...
    return someString
```

I want to apply this function to every item in a mysql table column,
something like:

```
UPDATE tbl SET mycol=pyfunc(mycol);
```

This update includes tens of millions of records.
Is there an efficient way to do this?

**Note: I cannot rewrite this function in sql or any other programming language.**

Comment: What about status of application? It should work? Is it possible to stop for a few minutes?

Comment: There is no active application using the database. I am preparing the database for future use.

Answer (score 0):

If your pyfunc does not depend on other data sources like apis or any cache, and just does some data processing like string or mathematical manipulations, or depends on the data stored in same database in mysql, you shall go for [MySQL user defined functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html).

Lets assume you create a MySQL function called `colFunc` , then your query would be

`Update tbl set mycol=colFunc(mycol)`

Comment: I cannot rewrite this function in sql or any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare `update.sql` file using python `script`.

After this you can check update on your local machine(with dump of db). Just connect to sql and run `update.sql` script which was prepared from python.

In this case you will use raw sql query without python for updating data.

I think it is not bad solution.